# @ManyToOne of the same type as parent where child doesn't exist in DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-roo

I used Spring Roo to reverse engineer a MySQL database, a db to which I only have read access.

One of the entities called Transaction has a field called originalTransaction, in the DB this is set that it can be null, but that the default value is 0.

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@RooDbManaged(automaticallyDelete = true)
@RooJpaActiveRecord(versionField = "", table = "TRANSACTIONS")
public class Transaction implements Serializable {

    ....

    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORIG_TRANS_ID")
    private Transaction originalTransaction;

    ....

}
```

FetchMode.Select and FetchType.Lazy I added as workarounds for other problems.

Now when I insert a transaction and I leave originalTransaction null, the DB changes it to 0.

When I do an entity().find(12345678), I get the following error:

```
Unable to find Transaction with id 0

javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Transaction with id 0
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:261)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
```

So obviously (which wasn't so obvious initially), it's trying to find the originalTransaction and since the DB changes the null to 0, it's trying to find Transaction with id=0 which doesn't exist - this causes entity.find(12345678) to return null even though the transaction is in the database.

Is there any workaround to stop Hibernate / JPA from bailing the search and returning null if the originalTransaction's id in the DB doesn't exist? I'd preferably force it to null if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings` always makes me twitch internally. :)  Still, +1 to your well-written question.

Comment: That @SuppressWarnings should actually go, the class is missing a "public static final long serialVersionUID = _____L;" Thanks for pointing out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Hibernate you can try

```
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

Otherwise you have to clean up your database (0 is not `null`). If there is no parent, the `ORIG_TRANS_ID` should be `null`

Comment: @NotFound is a way to circumnavigate the problem, anyway it causes an extra query with ID 0. The best solution is to keep a null value on that foreign key (using 0 as a FK is a really bad approach respect to DB design).
Maybe also a custom hibernate type could help, but I am not sure and I'd anyway prefer the approach suggested above.

Comment: @agori, if I had permissions to alter the DB, I would rip that out immediately, I think the main concern is downtime, the DB's been coming along for the past 10+ years, probably have 5-10 million records in that table and doing an alter table will cause the table to lock, not to mention breaking legacy code that depends on that 0.

Comment: @drkunibar, (at)NotFound, looks like it will solve the problem, thanks for the pointer!